# Set Date as a min date per ID with update

Tags: sql

I'm trying to set resolved date as a first date per user(ELSE CASE WHEN part of a code),
I need to make it in `CASE` statement, but `MIN()` function will just find minimum value in whole column, is there any way to do something like this in a code below?

```
UPDATE [ER].[dbo].[B]
SET   [Created]  =   A.Created,
      [Updated]  =   A.updated,
      [Resolved] = CASE WHEN (A.statusID <> 3 and B.StatusID = 3)
                                         THEN NULL
                                         ELSE CASE WHEN (A.statusID = 3 and B.StatusID = 3 and (A.resolutiondate > B.Resolved)) THEN MIN(A.resolutiondate) 
                                                ELSE B.Resolved
                                         END
                                  END,
         [StatusID] = A.StatusID,
         [Status] = A.StatusName,
         [Priority] = A.PriorityName,
         [Assignee] = A.Assignee,
         [Resolution] = A.resolution
FROM A
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar,A.ID) = [ER].[dbo].[B].ExternalId  and (B.Resolved IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `OVER PARITION BY` to get the min per subgroup / user. You can find details on this function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: So If I write
...THEN MIN(A.resolutiondate) OVER (PATRITION BY A.ID) in that part
that will be correct?
Are you sure it works it when/then statements?